# Standard Error Redirect in TCSH script

Tags: shell, redirect, csh, tcsh

I'm trying to make a simple TCSH script that effectively emulates **find** and outputs to a file; in addition I want to eliminate any error messages sent to Standard Error.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

ls $argv > filelist 2> /dev/null
```

The **find** portion of the script seems to work as should, but the Standard Error redirect doesn't. What's the best way to "eliminate" error messages?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you tried is `bash`y. In `tcsh`, you can do:

```
(ls $argv > filelist) >& /dev/null
```

Note that `>&` redirects *both* stdout and stderr, but since stdout has already been redirected elsewhere only the stderr will make it through to /dev/null.